# Не работает App::setLocale() в Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, cookie, сессия

Задача: Нужно в посреднике RegionMiddleware.php определить локализацию и использовать ее в контролёрах и в представлениях.

RegionMiddleware.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    App::setLocale('ru'); 
    return $next($request);
}
```

MainController.php

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('region');
}
public function index()
{
    echo App::getLocale();die;
}
```

Выведет в данном случае значение которое прописано в конфиге (en).
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно использовать `Lang::setLocale('ru');` вместо `App::setLocale('ru');`

Answer (score 0):

Дело может быть в том, что у Вас отсутствуют сами файлы локализации на нужный Вам язык, и поэтому локаль откатывается на дефолтную из конфига. 
[Вот здесь](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization) ещё попробуйте посмотреть.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но все файлы на месте.